# How create a library from react native app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

It is possible create a library from react native to use in android project? The same question for create objective-c library, like a pod.

In case of Android, this is my gradle:

```java
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

...


android {

  ...

  libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I change the plugin from `com.android.application` to `com.android.library` and change `applicationVariants` to `libraryVariants`.

But, when I try build the library, I got this error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Comment: just to clarify, you want to use react native code inside other app (iOS/Android)?

Comment: Hi there, stackOverflow is not a how-to site - but a problem solving site. Please provide us with an issue and some code to review! For reference, here is a link to how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a arquitecture problem... but yes, I put some code when I try solve this problem.

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue. I'm facing the same issue, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) in react native official doc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This document helps to integrate the application with a native application. what I was looking for is, how I can create a SDK to Android or IOs.

Comment: Do you want to create a package?

Comment: Yes. I want. Basically, I want write all code of the micro application inside a package to use from another application.